# C# - Regular expression to find a surrogate pair of a unicode codepoint from any string?

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, surrogate-pairs

I am trying to parse a message that possibly contains emojis in it. An example message that could be received looks like:

```
{"type":"chat","msg":"UserName:\u00a0\ud83d\ude0b \n"}
```

What should match is \u00a0 as a single character, and \ud83d\ude0b as a pair.

I have regex that can pull individual codes, but not pairs to match the full emoji:

```
\\u[a-z0-9]{4}
```

Is there a clean way to account for any/multiple emojis in a sentence so I can replace the surrogate pair with the function I have? Thanks!

Edit: Here is the function I will be using alongside the regex

```
string ConvertToUnicode(string SurrogatePair)
{
    string returnValue = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < SurrogatePair.Length; i += char.IsSurrogatePair(SurrogatePair, i) ? 2 : 1)
    {
        var codepoint = char.ConvertToUtf32(SurrogatePair, i);


        returnValue = String.Format("U+{0:X4}", codepoint);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

I have a dictionary where the key is unicode and the value is a reference to the emoji image so I can display it in a Unity UI element.

Edit 2:

As this question is a bit too broad, I will get specific as to what I am trying to accomplish. I am receiving a json message from a server through a websocket connection. This message is being displayed in a Unity Panel where each message is a text mesh pro text object. When an emoji is sent, the message displays similarly to the example message above, with the only change being that the surrogate pair changes based on the emoji sent. In order to insert the corresponding emoji image correctly into the text mesh pro object, I need to get the sprite atlas id that points to the correct emoji. As I did not insert the sprites by hand into the atlas but read them in from a spliced sprite sheet, the only way of accessing each image is by their indexed id. To correctly identify the emoji in the atlas by id, I created a dictionary that inserted the Unicode in order as they appeared in the sprite sheet as the key, where the value is the index in the atlas. What I am trying to do now is parse the message received for an emoji using regex, send this parsed data into the function I posted above to convert it to the Unicode value, then retrieve the correct id from the dictionary to finally insert the emoji that was originally entered on the front-end. If there is a better way of going about this please let me know, but from the research I did, the only efficient way to insert images into a Unity text object is how I am going about it. Due to this, I need to get the surrogate pairs from the message.

Edit 3:

If someone else happens to stumble upon this question i'll just leave my solution that I came up with for getting emojis from an html website, through a websocket server into Unity textmeshpro.

Here is a google spreadsheet containing the hex values and the sprite sheet I used to create the dictionary / sprite atlas in Unity: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XQY1n9cA1hx_PnsXoisxjanZRiQG0gd25VYEmk1W7mE/edit?usp=sharing.

I then used a library that can be found here: https://github.com/aaronpk/emoji-detector-php

It can parse a string and find emojis. I replaced the regex used with the regex provided by sln below, then tweaked the main script to just return the message text back but with the emojis replaced with the hex wrapped in a delimeter I could find with regex on the Unity side.

```
<?php
namespace Emoji;

define('LONGEST_EMOJI', 8);

function detect_emoji($string) {
  // Find all the emoji in the input string

  $prevencoding = mb_internal_encoding();
  mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

  $data = array();
    $test = $string;
  static $map;
  if(!isset($map))
    $map = _load_map();

  static $regexp;
  if(!isset($regexp))
    $regexp = _load_regexp();

  if(preg_match_all($regexp, $string, $matches)) {
    foreach($matches[0] as $ch) {
      $points = array();
      for($i=0; $i<mb_strlen($ch); $i++) {
        $points[] = strtoupper(dechex(uniord(mb_substr($ch, $i, 1))));
      }
      $hexstr = implode('-', $points);
        $theMatch = $string.exec($ch);

        $test = substr_replace($test, "[[[[".$hexstr."]]]]", strpos($test, $ch), strlen($ch));
    }
  }

  if($prevencoding)
    mb_internal_encoding($prevencoding);

  return $test;
}

function _load_map() {
  return json_decode(file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/map.json'), true);
}

function _load_regexp() {
  return '/(?:' . json_decode(file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/regexp.json')) . ')/u';
}

function uniord($c) {
  $ord0 = ord($c[0]); if ($ord0>=0   && $ord0<=127) return $ord0;
  $ord1 = ord($c[1]); if ($ord0>=192 && $ord0<=223) return ($ord0-192)*64 + ($ord1-128);
  $ord2 = ord($c[2]); if ($ord0>=224 && $ord0<=239) return ($ord0-224)*4096 + ($ord1-128)*64 + ($ord2-128);
  $ord3 = ord($c[3]); if ($ord0>=240 && $ord0<=247) return ($ord0-240)*262144 + ($ord1-128)*4096 + ($ord2-128)*64 + ($ord3-128);
  return false;
}
```

To call this in my server script, I just had to add:

```
include("src/Emoji.php");
```

at the top of my script, and call the function as follows:

```
$message = Emoji\detect_emoji($message);
```

I made sure this was only sent to my Unity client as I was storing their resourceId in the server code.

On the Unity side, to find the emojis that need to be replaced, I used:

```
string emojiPattern = @"(?<=\[\[\[\[).[^\]\]\]\]]*";

 MatchCollection emojiMatch = Regex.Matches(messageString, emojiPattern);

            for(int x = 0; x < emojiMatch.Count; x++)
            { 
                messageString =  messageString.Replace("[[[[" + emojiMatch[x].Value +  "]]]]", "<sprite=" + emojiDictionary[emojiMatch[x].Value.ToLower()].ToString() + ">");
            }
```

As the text element, I was instantiating was a text mesh pro text GUI element, it is able to convert the  to an image in the sprite atlas I made using the sprite sheet. Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: `so I can replace the surrogate pair` Are you looking for a Utf-16 regex for _all emoji_ or are you looking for a regex for surrogate pairs. I have both what you want ?

Comment: The regex for surrogate pairs is `[\x{D800}-\x{DBFF}][\x{DC00}-\x{DFFF}]` where You could also use `[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]`. Where `\ud83d\ude0b` will embed as character `` and be matched by the surrogate pair regex. Remember, this will match all surrogate pairs, emoji or not. https://regex101.com/r/aEmB0V/1

Comment: BTW, a lot of [new emojis](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts-11.0/full-emoji-list.html) do not only consist of two bytes, some consist of three or more. So, just `[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]` might not be enough.

Comment: @sln Preferably all emojis. I am passing the returned match from the regex with a Regex.replace with the function I added to the post with an edit.

Comment: Your question is vague and very broad. But it seems to me that you're going about this the wrong way. It appears you are receiving JSON, and then trying to manipulate the JSON itself. IMHO, this is wrong. You should decode/deserialize the JSON first. Then you won't be dealing with escapes at all. You'll have actual UTF16 characters (i.e. in the .NET `string` type). Then, you can search for and extract emojis just by matching the actual `string` value that represents each one of interest. This `string` value may be a pair of surrogates, or longer, depending on the emoji.

Comment: If I were building a table of emoji characters to glyphs (as e.g. a browser, text messaging app, etc. would do), I would store the emoji as a UTF32 string, as the official emoji tables are represented this way, i.e. as a sequence of one or more Unicode code points (i.e. characters). My C# program would then load this, converting from the UTF32 encoding to the UTF16 encoding .NET uses for the purposes of a lookup table (dictionary), and then I would use the decoded JSON strings for the lookup. ...

Comment: … For additional performance, you might have a multi-level lookup where the first lookup is based on a single UTF16 character, so that you can scan a string and quickly ignore character sequences that can't possibly be an emoji, due to them not starting with a UTF16 character that is among those that emojis start with (there are a relatively small number of those, with little overlap with other non-emoji characters).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I am receiving json and am trying to display the message in a Unity Panel filled with textMeshPro text objects. I have a sprite atlas that is ordered by unicode value. As I auto generated the atlas from a sprite sheet, there is no unicode value assigned to each emoji. To fix this I created a dictionary with the key being the unicode of the emoji and the value being the index the emoji appears in the sprite atlas. The way textmeshpro can insert images into text is by using <image=#> where # is an id in the atlas. I need the string literal of the unicode for this to work.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I was unsure of how else to go about this. I pulled the emoji sprites and unicode order from a website that listed all of the relevant data. Is there a way to encode unicode as the string literal instead of the data I am recieving now?

Comment: _"Is there a way to encode unicode as the string literal instead of the data I am recieving now?"_ -- since the data is being encoded as a (JSON) string literal already, I don't understand your question. As already noted, it is a mistake to view emojis in strings as if they are always surrogate pairs. An emoji is represented by one or more Unicode characters, which in turn are themselves represented as surrogate pairs when encoded as UTF16 (as they are in a .NET `string` type). You are on the right track with your dictionary to map string values to indexes.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sorry my question is a bit confusing. I was wondering if there was a way to prior to encoding my data as json to convert any emojis to a string of its unicode. So if a message on my front-end was to contain an emoji , it would package and send the data as U+1F600, but as a string not the unicode value.

Comment: You want to literally send a string containing `"U+1F600"`? I.e. the letter `'U'`, followed by `'+'`, then the hexadecimal representation of the emoji? First, I fail to see the point in that, when you could just send a string. Second, again: an emoji may be one or more such Unicode code points. Check out the table that [Wiktor pointed you to](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts-11.0/full-emoji-list.html). Many emojis require two Unicode code points, and a few at the end require _seven_.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I would need the string as I mentioned as that is the key in my dictionary. I'm pretty sure server side in php I can find all of the emojis using a preg_replace, then convert them to their entire expanded hex regardless of the amount of unicode they are represented by. I could use something like mb_convert_encoding, convert from UTF-8 to UTF-32 then package the unicode between some sort of delimiter I can search for when receiving it. I do not necessarily need the 'U+', the dictionary just stores the hex of the emoji.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete C# regex to find any/all V12 Emoji

```
[#*0-9]\uFE0F\u20E3|[\u00A9\u00AE\u203C\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21A9\u21AA\u231A\u231B\u2328\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611\u2614\u2615\u2618]|\u261D(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2640\u2642\u2648-\u2653\u265F\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267E\u267F\u2692-\u2697\u2699\u269B\u269C\u26A0\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26B0\u26B1\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26C8\u26CE\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3\u26D4\u26E9\u26EA\u26F0-\u26F5\u26F7\u26F8]|\u26F9(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?|\uFE0F\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?|[\u26FA\u26FD\u2702\u2705\u2708\u2709]|[\u270A-\u270D](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\u270F\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721\u2728\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2763\u2764\u2795-\u2797\u27A1\u27B0\u27BF\u2934\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55\u3030\u303D\u3297\u3299]|\uD83C(?:[\uDC04\uDCCF\uDD70\uDD71\uDD7E\uDD7F\uDD8E\uDD91-\uDD9A]|\uDDE6\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFD\uDDFF]|\uDDE7\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEF\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDE8\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDEE\uDDF0-\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA-\uDDFF]|\uDDE9\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEF\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDFF]|\uDDEA\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDED\uDDF7-\uDDFA]|\uDDEB\uD83C[\uDDEE-\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF7]|\uDDEC\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEE\uDDF1-\uDDF3\uDDF5-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFE]|\uDDED\uD83C[\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFA]|\uDDEE\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEA\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9]|\uDDEF\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF5]|\uDDF0\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDEE\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDF1\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDE8\uDDEE\uDDF0\uDDF7-\uDDFB\uDDFE]|\uDDF2\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDFF]|\uDDF3\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF4\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA\uDDFF]|\uDDF4\uD83C\uDDF2|\uDDF5\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEA-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDF3\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFC\uDDFE]|\uDDF6\uD83C\uDDE6|\uDDF7\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF4\uDDF8\uDDFA\uDDFC]|\uDDF8\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDF4\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFD-\uDDFF]|\uDDF9\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDED\uDDEF-\uDDF4\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFF]|\uDDFA\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEC\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF8\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDFB\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF3\uDDFA]|\uDDFC\uD83C[\uDDEB\uDDF8]|\uDDFD\uD83C\uDDF0|\uDDFE\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF9]|\uDDFF\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDF2\uDDFC]|[\uDE01\uDE02\uDE1A\uDE2F\uDE32-\uDE3A\uDE50\uDE51\uDF00-\uDF21\uDF24-\uDF84]|\uDF85(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDF86-\uDF93\uDF96\uDF97\uDF99-\uDF9B\uDF9E-\uDFC1]|\uDFC2(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDFC3\uDFC4](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|[\uDFC5\uDFC6]|\uDFC7(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDFC8\uDFC9]|\uDFCA(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|[\uDFCB\uDFCC](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?|\uFE0F\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?|[\uDFCD-\uDFF0]|\uDFF3(?:\uFE0F\u200D\uD83C\uDF08)?|\uDFF4(?:\u200D\u2620\uFE0F|\uDB40\uDC67\uDB40\uDC62\uDB40(?:\uDC65\uDB40\uDC6E\uDB40\uDC67|\uDC73\uDB40\uDC63\uDB40\uDC74|\uDC77\uDB40\uDC6C\uDB40\uDC73)\uDB40\uDC7F)?|[\uDFF5\uDFF7-\uDFFF])|\uD83D(?:[\uDC00-\uDC14]|\uDC15(?:\u200D\uD83E\uDDBA)?|[\uDC16-\uDC40]|\uDC41(?:\uFE0F\u200D\uD83D\uDDE8\uFE0F)?|[\uDC42\uDC43](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDC44\uDC45]|[\uDC46-\uDC50](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDC51-\uDC65]|[\uDC66\uDC67](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDC68(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F|\u2764\uFE0F\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?|[\uDC68\uDC69]\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?)|[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92])|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C(?:\uDFFB(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD]))?|\uDFFC(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C\uDFFB|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFD(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFE(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFF(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?))?|\uDC69(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F|\u2764\uFE0F\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?[\uDC68\uDC69]|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?|\uDC69\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?)|[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92])|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C(?:\uDFFB(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFC-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFC(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFD-\uDFFF]|\uDC69\uD83C\uDFFB)|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFD(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC\uDFFE\uDFFF]|\uDC69\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC])|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFE(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD\uDFFF]|\uDC69\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD])|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFF(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?))?|\uDC6A|[\uDC6B-\uDC6D](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDC6E(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|\uDC6F(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?|\uDC70(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDC71(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|\uDC72(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDC73(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|[\uDC74-\uDC76](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDC77(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|\uDC78(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDC79-\uDC7B]|\uDC7C(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDC7D-\uDC80]|[\uDC81\uDC82](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|\uDC83(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDC84|\uDC85(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDC86\uDC87](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|[\uDC88-\uDCA9]|\uDCAA(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDCAB-\uDCFD\uDCFF-\uDD3D\uDD49-\uDD4E\uDD50-\uDD67\uDD6F\uDD70\uDD73]|\uDD74(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDD75(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?|\uFE0F\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?|[\uDD76-\uDD79]|\uDD7A(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDD87\uDD8A-\uDD8D]|[\uDD90\uDD95\uDD96](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDDA4\uDDA5\uDDA8\uDDB1\uDDB2\uDDBC\uDDC2-\uDDC4\uDDD1-\uDDD3\uDDDC-\uDDDE\uDDE1\uDDE3\uDDE8\uDDEF\uDDF3\uDDFA-\uDE44]|[\uDE45-\uDE47](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|[\uDE48-\uDE4A]|\uDE4B(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|\uDE4C(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDE4D\uDE4E](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|\uDE4F(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDE80-\uDEA2]|\uDEA3(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|[\uDEA4-\uDEB3]|[\uDEB4-\uDEB6](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|[\uDEB7-\uDEBF]|\uDEC0(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDEC1-\uDEC5\uDECB]|\uDECC(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDECD-\uDED2\uDED5\uDEE0-\uDEE5\uDEE9\uDEEB\uDEEC\uDEF0\uDEF3-\uDEFA\uDFE0-\uDFEB])|\uD83E(?:[\uDD0D\uDD0E]|\uDD0F(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDD10-\uDD17]|[\uDD18-\uDD1C](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDD1D|[\uDD1E\uDD1F](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDD20-\uDD25]|\uDD26(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|[\uDD27-\uDD2F]|[\uDD30-\uDD36](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDD37(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|[\uDD38\uDD39](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|\uDD3A|\uDD3C(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?|[\uDD3D\uDD3E](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|[\uDD3F-\uDD45\uDD47-\uDD71\uDD73-\uDD76\uDD7A-\uDDA2\uDDA5-\uDDAA\uDDAE-\uDDB4]|[\uDDB5\uDDB6](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDDB7|[\uDDB8\uDDB9](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|\uDDBA|\uDDBB(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDDBC-\uDDCA]|[\uDDCD-\uDDCF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|\uDDD0|\uDDD1(?:\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1|\uD83C(?:\uDFFB(?:\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C\uDFFB)?|\uDFFC(?:\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC])?|\uDFFD(?:\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD])?|\uDFFE(?:\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE])?|\uDFFF(?:\u200D\uD83E\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?))?|[\uDDD2-\uDDD5](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDDD6(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|[\uDDD7-\uDDDD](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?)?|[\uDDDE\uDDDF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F)?|[\uDDE0-\uDDFF\uDE70-\uDE73\uDE78-\uDE7A\uDE80-\uDE82\uDE90-\uDE95])
```

Comment: Thanks! Along with a bunch of other stuff, this regex helped me get emojis in Unity!